# How to replace value of multidimensional array when key present in another array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

I have one array with state codes and their full names, like this:

```
$first_array=array("AB"=>"Alberta","BC"=>"British Columbia");
```

I have another array with ids and state codes, like this:

```
$result_array=array(15=>array("ad_id"=>15,"state code"=>"AB"));
```

I want to replace the `state code` values in `$result_array` with the corresponding "full name" in `$first_array`.

If there is no corresponding value in `$first_array` then the `state code` in `$result_array` should remain unchanged.

This is my expected result:

```
$result_array=array(15=>array("ad_id"=>15,"state code"=>"Alberta"));
```

Comment: Below is my result array

Comment: my result array,
Array (
   [15] => array (
       [ad_id] => 15 
       [state code] => **AB**
      )
   )
   
 but  I want below array
Array (
   [15] => array (
       [ad_id] => 15 
       [state code] => **Alberta**
         )
   )

Comment: try using `array_search()` for finding key value and replace it with another variable

Comment: `array_walk($resultArray, function (&$value) use ($first_array) { $value['state_code'] = $first_array[$value['state_code']]; });`

Comment: `array_walk` is better. Missed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
$first_array= array("AB"=>"Alberta","BC"=>"British Columbia");

$second_array = array(
15 => array ( 'ad_id' => 15, 'state code' => 'AB' ) ,
16 => array ( 'ad_id' => 16, 'state code' => 'CD' ) 
);

$new = array_map(function($a) use($first_array) {
    return array(
        'ad_id' => $a['ad_id'],
        'state code' => !empty($first_array[$a['state code']]) ? $first_array[$a['state code']] : $a['state code'],
    );
}, $second_array);

print_r($new);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [ad_id] => 15
            [state code] => Alberta
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [ad_id] => 16
            [state code] => CD
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
$first_array=["AB"=>"Alberta","BC"=>"British Columbia"];
$result_array=[
    15=>['ad_id'=>15,'state code'=>'AB'],
    16=>['ad_id'=>16,'state code'=>'BC'],
    17=>['ad_id'=>17,'state code'=>'NY']
];
```

Method #1 - `array_walk()`

```
array_walk($result_array,function(&$a)use($first_array){
    if(isset($first_array[$a['state code']])){  // only overwrite state code if full name is available
        $a['state code']=$first_array[$a['state code']];
    }
});
```

Method #2 - `foreach()`

```
foreach($result_array as $k=>$a){
    if(isset($first_array[$a['state code']])){  // only overwrite state code if full name is available
        $result_array[$k]['state code']=$first_array[$a['state code']];
    }   
}
```

Output (from either method): `var_export($result_array);`

```
array (
  15 => 
  array (
    'ad_id' => 15,
    'state code' => 'Alberta',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'ad_id' => 16,
    'state code' => 'British Columbia',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'ad_id' => 17,
    'state code' => 'NY',
  ),
)
```